# Display time from number in excel number format

Tags: excel, number-formatting

I currently have a table with a set of dated columns, each row then has a persons name where under each date, a number denoting the number of minutes they have completed in training. i.e.  5 example rows for 1/10/2013 may be 30, 25, 60, 45, 15. I would like to be able to format that within HH:MM:SS but keeping the data its self the same so that the appropriate calculations can be done on the data.

1. Is this possible using excel number formatting?
2. if not, is this possible using anything other than VBA?
3. if this is only possible using VBA, is it possible to convert HH:MM:SS back to MM only within a formula.

Comment: + 1 Good question :) Had me thinking for a while...

Answer (score 2):

In Excel, times are stored as numerics, with 1 day (=24 hrs) representing figure "1", i.e. hours and minutes are fractions of "1";

hence, to convert figure "45" (expressing minutes) into Excel time you would use `=45/60/24` and format as time, e.g. "mm:ss". (suggested answer for your pt 2 and 3)

You can use the so converted time for calculations in the same way as your originals. If you add times and expect results > 00:59:59 minutes or > 23:59:59 hours, use "[hh]:mm:ss" or "[mm]:ss" custom format strings.

Easiest would be to enter "45" as time directly by typing "0:45" into a cell.

To get out minutes of a time you can use `=MINUTE(<datetime>)` ... result is 0..59 ... so for more than 60 minutes you also need to do `=HOUR(<datetime>)`.

**EDIT:**
if you are only keen ***displaying*** "45" as "45:00", use custom format **00":00"** (meaning to display 2 numeric digits followed by constant string ":00" ... which will display numeric value 2 as "02:00" and numeric value 45 as "45:00"; kinda fake, but ... ;)

Comment: I would like to avoid changing the data as there can be around 25 - 30 rows and up to 365 columns (Potentially around 11,000 cells to edit). All the data comes from an export, if i was to start changing the data, this would defy the object of trying to make this simpler by using a number format.

Comment: no need to change ... if it's just for displaying, create another cell beside/below the original "45" using the mentioned formula and display it as "mm:ss"; actually @Siddharth is doing the same by dividing /24/60, using the range/pastespecial/divide method

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very interesting way of doing it. This method doesn't involve `VBA` or `Formulas`

Let's say your Excel sheet looks like this

[image]

Now enter `60` in any blank cell in a sheet. For demonstration purpose, I will do it below the above range... say in Cell `A4`

[image]

Next copy your cell `A4 (cell which has 60)` and then right click on the range `A1:E2` and click on `Paste Special`. Next select `Values` under `Paste` and `Divide` under `Operation`

[image]

You will get this.

[image]

Now change the value in cell `A4` to `24` and repeat the above process.

[image]

You will get this

[image]

Now simply custom format your range `A1:E2` as `[hh]:mm:ss` and you will get your results

[image]